# How to fix warning "the compiler can assume that the address of 'object' will never be NULL"

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

I use gcc8 to compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class person
{
    public:
        virtual void setage()=0;
};

void test(person &object)
{
    if (&object == NULL) {
        std::cout << "NULL object1" << std::endl;
    }

    if (!(&object)) 
    {
        std::cout << "NULL object1" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    person *object=NULL;
    person &object1=*object;

    test(object1);
}
```

Then, two warnings come out after compiling and running:

> $g++ -std=c++14 -pthread -fgnu-tm  -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread
>   -pedantic-errors main.cpp -lm  -latomic -lstdc++fs  && ./a.out
>
> main.cpp: In function 'void test(person&)':
>
> main.cpp:11:17: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of
>   'object' will never be NULL [-Waddress]
>
> ```
>  if (&object == NULL) {
>
>              ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:15:18: warning: the compiler can assume that the address of
>   'object' will never be NULL [-Waddress]
>
> ```
>  if (!(&object))
>
>               ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:15:5: warning: nonnull argument 'object' compared to NULL
>   [-Wnonnull-compare]
>
> ```
>  if (!(&object))
>
>  ^~
> ```
>
> main.cpp:11:5: warning: nonnull argument 'object' compared to NULL
>   [-Wnonnull-compare]
>
> ```
>  if (&object == NULL) {
>
>  ^~
> ```

1. Why is the address of `object` in function `test` not NULL even passing a NULL reference value to it?
2. It seems that reference `object` in function `test` can never be NULL, so we can just remove the code `if (&object == NULL){...}` and `if (&object == NULL) {...}` to avoid these two warnings, right?

Thanks for hints.

Comment: `&object` can never be `NULL`. You are checking the address of an object that will always exist. The compiler tells you that the condition can be removed. The line `person &object1=*object;` in your main function tries to dereference a NULL pointer and will cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: @MrPromethee I use coliru to compile and run it, there is no segmentation fault https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/404da4c7eeedd154

Comment: You're right sorry, it's actually undefined behaviour. My point is that you should not dereference NULL pointers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

References are never null in a well-formed C++ program. The only valid way to initialize a reference is to bind it to a valid object. The only way a "null reference" may happen is if one derefernces a null pointer, as you have. But then the behavior of your program is undefined even before you check `&object == NULL`. The bug is in the code that passes the "null reference", and it *must* be fixed there.

So the compiler is warning you that you added a superfluous check, that protects you from little to nothing, because the broken code that needs to be fixed is outside your function.

Answer (score 4):

```
Person* ptr_object = NULL;
Person& ref_object= *ptr_object;
```

By dereferencing ptr_object here you are dereferencing a NULL pointer, which is undefined behavior. A reference should not be referencing to NULL.